# Adjective for having bugs

Tags: adjectives, terminology

E.g. when you want to say that this piece of software has a lot of bug. Can I use something like buggy or bugged?

Comment: Yes, "buggy" ... Or be fancier and say "bug-ridden", "bug-filled", "Bug-infested".

Comment: Usage example of _buggy_: [Buggy software: Why do we put up with it?](http://www.zdnet.com/article/buggy-software-why-do-we-put-up-with-it/)

Comment: Yep, "buggy".  Since the 70s for sure, likely much farther back than that.

Comment: [Its provenance apparently goes back to the 19th century](https://www.wired.com/2013/12/googles-doodle-honors-grace-hopper-and-entomology/).

Comment: @GEdgar That comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "buggy" ... Or be fancier and say "bug-ridden", "bug-filled", "Bug-infested"

Bu not "bugged" ... that means something with a concealed listening device.  Certain software may be bugged as well as buggy.

Comment: I'm watching twitch and many streamers (native speakers) refer to bugs in a game (software) as bugged. Like "yep, it's bugged"